# String is not identical to NSObject error , while applying constraints in Swift (visual constraints)

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, nslayoutconstraint

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
class DetailView: UIViewController{
    var fullImage:UIImageView?
    var nameLabel:UILabel?
    var detailLabel:UILabel?

    override  func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fullImage = UIImageView()
        nameLabel = UILabel()
        detailLabel = UILabel()
        self.view.addSubview(fullImage!)
        self.view.addSubview(nameLabel!)
        self.view.addSubview(detailLabel!)
    }

    func applyContraints(){
        self.view.addSubview(fullImage!)

     fullImage?.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
     nameLabel?.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
     detailLabel?.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        var viewsDict:[String:AnyObject!] = ["imageView": fullImage!, "nameLabel": nameLabel!, "detailLabel": detailLabel!]

        var constraints:NSArray

        constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-10-[imageView]-10-|",
            options: 0,
            metrics: nil,
            views: viewsDict)
        self.view.addConstraints(constraints)



    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `views` param of `constraintsWithVisualFormat` expects a Dictionary of type `[NSObject: AnyObject]`.

When creating the `viewsDict`, try declaring it as `[NSObject: AnyObject]`:

```
var viewsDict: [NSObject: AnyObject] = ["imageView": fullImage!, "nameLabel": nameLabel!, "detailLabel": detailLabel!]
```

You're also going to have to change the `options` param value from `0` to `nil`

Also, if you'd like to get rid of the optionals, you could try the following:

```
var fullImage = UIImageView()
var nameLabel = UILabel()
var detailLabel = UILabel()
```

Instead of:

```
var fullImage: UIImageView?
var nameLabel: UILabel?
var detailLabel: UILabel?
```

Then, for the `viewsDict` declaration you can remove the `!`:

```
var viewsDict: [NSObject: AnyObject] = ["imageView": fullImage, "nameLabel": nameLabel, "detailLabel": detailLabel]
```

Comment: hey Brian , i gave it as optional to avoid init() function of class , and thanks option nil is working

Comment: @SandyRawat glad it's working! Actually, if you use the method I showed you above by setting the variables to an initial value, you don't need an `init` at all.

Answer (score 5):

Please change `options:0` to `options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0)`, which is the correct syntax here.

Comment: @SandyRawat Then you should select the checkmark next to gabbler's answer so it's easier for future answer-seekers to find.